# Calculating mean values based on two different groupings in a data frame

Tags: r, plyr, mean

I would like calculate mean values based on two different groupings in my data frame. 
An example data set is:

```
> data
     age Year Length
[1,]   3 2004   23.2
[2,]   3 2004   27.6
[3,]   3 2005   25.4
[4,]   3 2005   22.2
[5,]   4 2004   37.6
[6,]   4 2004   31.3
[7,]   4 2005   29.9
[8,]   4 2005   30.1
```

So far, I have used the ddply function to calculate means within one age grouping. To do this I've created an index to sort all of the three year old data and then found the means of length within Year.

```
logical3=(mydata$Age ==3)
mydata3= mydata[logical3,]
mean_values_3 <- ddply(mydata3, "Year", transform, grp.mean.values=mean(Length))
```

I'd like to make the process faster and less clunky by calculating means without sorting by age first.

Is there a way to 1) find mean values based upon more than 1 groups-This grouping does not need to be done sequentially- and 2) how can I get the means to output into a separate data frame and not append to the working one.

Comment: Try the formula method of `aggregate`.  See `?aggregate`.  In your case, something like `result` <- aggregate(Length ~ age + year, data = data, FUN = mean)` or something close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `aggregate` function. Probably something like this:

```
example_data <- data.frame(age=c(3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                           Year=c(2004,2004,2005,2005,2004,2004,2005,2005),
                           Length=c(23.2,27.6,25.4,22.2,37.6,31.3,29.9,30.1))

aggregate(x=example_data$Length,
          by=list(example_data$age,example_data$Year),
          FUN=mean)

  Group.1 Group.2     x
1       3    2004 25.40
2       4    2004 34.45
3       3    2005 23.80
4       4    2005 30.00
```

Comment: Alternatively you can write `aggregate` this way `aggregate(Length ~ age + Year, FUN=mean, data=example_data)` to avoid calling `example_data` and using `$` several times.

Comment: A little bit late, but this should be marked as the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the `plyr` package. It can summarize your data with simple code. The c("Year","age") is how you specify the group variables. You can also include many summary statistical functions with this package. This code will return a separate data frame with the columns of the grouping variables and the group means. NO sorting required.

```
group.means<-ddply(data,c("Year","age"),summarise,mean=mean(Length))
group.means
```